# How can I unpack this archive file?

Tags: unpacking, struct

I recently discovered a binary container file in a GameCube video game which I cannot unpack!

I asked around, and I was told that it is an archive with this exact file structure:

```
char Signature[8];
uint32 FileCount;
uint32 Size;
char Padding?[16];
FileDesc Files[FileCount];

struct FileDesc
{
char Filename[32];
uint32 Offset;
uint32 Size;
char Padding?[24];
};
```

But I cannot figure out how to write a working script in Python which can unpack this file!

Literally all I want is to unpack the archive and retrieve the files inside!

[Here is the file in question.](https://mega.nz/#!10YlCBqb!uAfVjf6KkRdNZPpBqJmIaa8zTzh_YCkCm8b9mkPdYYY)

Comment: Have a look at http://kaitai.io

Answer (score 1):

Please read this article of mine: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5035/How-to-Write-a-Simple-Packer-Unpacker-with-a-Self

It answers you in C. But rewriting in Python is easy.